# Adding and removing items from ng-repeat, simple cart implementation, using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to achieve an array with items that displays as a title and image and when the user click the title the item should be added to a div. However, I can´t make it to work as when I click on "Add me", there is only a blank item added, with no image and no title.
I got the delete-function to work but not the add-function.

Here is what I got:
The "Add me"-button and the list of items

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in items.data">
        <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a> <img ng-src="{{ item.image }}" /><a ng-click="deleteItem($index)" class="delete-item">x</a>
        <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Me</button>
    </li>
```

The array

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.factory("items", function () {
var items = {};
items.data = [{
    title: "Item 1",
    image: "img/item01.jpg"
}, {
    title: "Item 2",
    image: "img/item02.jpg"
}, {
    title: "Item 3",
    image: "img/item03.jpg"
}, {
    title: "Item 4",
    image: "img/item04.jpg"
}];
  return items;
});
```

And the functions for add and delete

```
function ItemsController($scope, items) {
$scope.items = items;

$scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
    items.data.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.addItem = function () {
    items.data.push({
        title: $scope.items.title
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: What is `$scope.items.title` ?

Comment: Why is there two add buttons?

Comment: I tried to use `{{item.title}}` to display the title from the list, but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the item under iteration.

```
<button ng-click="addItem(item)">Add Me</button>
```

and add the title to the newly added:

```
  $scope.addItem = function(item) {
    items.data.push({
      title: item.title
    });
  }
```

it is better not to use `$index` (it can cause issue when used with filters eg: orderBy filter) instead just pass the item to delete and:

```
   $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
     items.data.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1);
   }
```

You also have an invalid html, `li` must be a child of `ul` or `ol`.

A sample implementation:

```
 function($scope, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.cart = [];

  $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    var cart = $scope.cart;
    //Get matched item from the cart
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    //if more than one match exists just reduce the count
    if (match.count > 1) {
      match.count -= 1;
      return;
    }
    //Remove the item if current count is 1
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
  }

  $scope.addItem = function(item) {
    //Get matched item from the cart
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item), itemToAdd ;
     //if item exists just increase the count
    if (match) {
      match.count += 1;
      return;
    }

    //Push the new item to the cart
    itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
    itemToAdd.count = 1;

    $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
  }

  function getMatchedCartItem(item) {
    /*array.find - Find the shim for it in the demo*/
    return $scope.cart.find(function(itm) {
      return itm.id === item.id
    });

  }
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.cart = [];

  $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    var cart = $scope.cart;
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match.count > 1) {
      match.count -= 1;
      return;
    }
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
  }

  $scope.addItem = function(item) {
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match) {
      match.count += 1;
      return;
    }
    var itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
    itemToAdd.count = 1;
    $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
  }

  function getMatchedCartItem(item) {
    return $scope.cart.find(function(itm) {
      return itm.id === item.id
    });

  }

}).factory("items", function() {
  var items = {};
  items.data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 1",
    image: "img/item01.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 2",
    image: "img/item02.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: "Item 3",
    image: "img/item03.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: "Item 4",
    image: "img/item04.jpg"
  }];
  return items;
});

if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items.data" id="item{{item.id}}">
      <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a> 
      <img ng-src="{{ item.image }}" />
      <button ng-click="addItem(item)">Add Me</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Cart:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in cart">
      <a href="#">{{item.title}} | Count: {{item.count}}</a> 
      <a ng-click="deleteItem(item)" class="delete-item">X</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you would need to add the shim (as mentioned in the demo) to be able to make it work for non supported browsers.

Comment: Yes, it works! I think I understand the changes, I felt I was close to a solution :) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @jodor i have added explanation, see my answer update. Also i am using array.find.

Comment: @PSL can you please add code to calculate price of item based on qty? Also total of cart. Thanks :)